# python keras SyntaxError: invalid syntax: f'at {latest_checkpoint}. Retrying. '

Tags: python, keras, import

I got

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax: f'at {latest_checkpoint}. Retrying. '

when I tried the code, height.py ()
The error occurred when importing keras

```
File "height.py", line 9, in <module>
    from keras import layers
  File "/home/jekang39/anaconda2/envs/dl_gwas/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from keras import distribute
  File "/home/jekang39/anaconda2/envs/dl_gwas/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/distribute/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from keras.distribute import sidecar_evaluator
  File "/home/jekang39/anaconda2/envs/dl_gwas/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/distribute/sidecar_evaluator.py", line 209
    f'at {latest_checkpoint}. Retrying. '
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If anyone has a clue to solve the error, kindly let me know

Comment: Check you python version. python < 3.6 doesn't support that syntax

Answer (score 1):

Go to location -> .local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/<your_file_name_in_which_it_shows_error>.py

The problem is the extra "f" letter that is added here. That is why it shows error.
Manually open that file in a text editor and remove that letter "f". It should be 'at {latest_checkpoint}. Retrying. '

It worked for me